# Display cell content in a text box in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of cells with data. I want a text box to show the cell content when I click on any cell in the text box. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: do you have any exiting code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows

For i = 1 To lRow
If Cells(i, 1).Count = 1 Then
If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
Else
If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(i, 1)) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox (i)
End If
End If
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This will show the value in a message box, not a text box. Not sure why you need a text box.

i refers to the row and change the `1` in `lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows` to the correct column number you are working in

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the worksheet (see the black arrow):[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox Target.Value

End Sub
```

In general, if you want to check for a specific range, you can define the range in the event:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngPreselected As Range
    Set rngPreselected = Range("A1:B10")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngPreselected) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Target.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

In this case, `A1:B10` is the defined range.

That's called `Event`. See more about events here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.aspx